# ASP.NET MVC - GridViewEditingMode.PopupEditForm doesn't show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress, modal-dialog

I have a strange problem with Devexpress MVC extensions. I created a grid and enabled CommandColumns in order to have an ability to add, edit and delete rows.

```
 @model IEnumerable
    @{
        var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
                                                  {
                                                      settings.Name = "dxGridView";
                                                      settings.Width = Unit.Pixel(678);
                                                      settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.PopupEditForm;
                                                      settings.SettingsEditing.PopupEditFormModal = true;
                                                      settings.KeyFieldName = "ID";
                                                      settings.CallbackRouteValues = new {Controller = "Home", Action = "ContentPartial"};
                                                      settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
                                                      settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;
                                                      settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
                                                      settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Text = "Delete";
                                                      settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
                                                      settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Text = "New";
                                                      settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new {Controller = "Home", Action = "AddPartial"};
                                                      settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new {Controller = "Home", Action = "EditPartial"};
                                                      settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new {Controller = "Home", Action = "DeletePartial"};

                                                      settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;
                                                             settings.SetEditFormTemplateContent(x =>
                                                {
                                                    Html.DevExpress().Label(val => val.Text = "Afasdfsadfsadfsdafasfasdf").Render();
                                                    Html.DevExpress().Button(
                                                        btnSettings =>
                                                        {
                                                            btnSettings.Name = "btnUpdate";
                                                            btnSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
                                                            btnSettings.Text = "Update";
                                                            btnSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ dxGridView.UpdateEdit(); }";
                                                        }
                                                        )
                                                        .Render();
                                                    Html.DevExpress().Button(
                                                        btnSettings =>
                                                        {
                                                            btnSettings.Name = "btnCancel";
                                                            btnSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
                                                            btnSettings.Text = "Cancel";
                                                            btnSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ javascript:pcModalMode.Show(); }";
                                                        }
                                                        )
                                                        .Render();
                                                });
    }

    @grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml();
```

As You can see I set simple content for edit form. The problem is that after I click button "New" or "Edit" popup is not shown. 
    settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.PopupEditForm;
is the only setting which is not working. Inline mode and other modes works fine, but I need to open a popup.

Answer (score 1):

This issue looks strange. Your code is similar to the ["Grid View - Inline Editing (Templates)"](http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/InlineEditingWithTemplate) demo.

Just in case, remove the "javascript" substring from the following code section:

```
//btnSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ javascript:pcModalMode.Show(); }";
btnSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ pcModalMode.Show(); }";
```

This prefix is no longer required.